# Simplest and ad-free Android Notepad App

Tags: android, text-editor, note-taking

All the Android Notepad Apps I found on the google play boast their rich feature selection, but I'm just looking for an Android Notepad App that has the simplest features, just like the simple Notepad provided by Microsoft.

All that I'm asking for is a place for me to copy my text selections over, so text from difference sources can be gathered into a single place and maybe rearranged, and edited a bit. That's it.

Does such simplest Notepad App ever exist? And most importantly, it has to be ad-free, because the least thing I want when organizing my thought is those flashy ads that try their best to grasp your eyeballs.

**UPDATE:** Well, after my first post, I made my last attempt to find it myself, and found this,

**Fast notepad**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taxaly.noteme&hl=en
The simplest in the world notepad. Nothing extra, no ads, loads instantly.

That looks good, but last update was over two years ago, on February 17, 2013. Is there anything better than this?

Comment: If it comes to simplest then **Simplenote** or **Notes** gives competition to Notepad (both on Play Store). However, I have AdAway  installed so I don't know about ads here.

Comment: try this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.workpail.inkpad.notepad.notes&hl=en

Comment: Oh, although it is called Notepad, it is actually a To do list pad. But thanks anyway. Someone might find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [EasyWriter (Writer Plus)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.easy4u.writer)

EasyWriter+ is actually a small, fast Markdown editor for Android, but easily meets the specifications OP supplied in the original question:

- [image: Yes] Android notepad App that has the simplest features
- [image: Yes] a place for me to copy my text selections ... maybe rearranged, and edited a bit
- [image: Yes] and most importantly, it has to be ad-free
- as **bonus** supports a nice subset of Markdown markup.

[image: file system]

[image: editing]

I've been using it for a few months now, and am very happy with it.

Comment: Thanks, just double-check, it is really "Absolutely FREE", or it is Ads supported?

Comment: No ads - "absolutely free", as the developer puts it. :) And the dev seems to be quite responsive to user input, too. Nice app.

Comment: Great. I'll be still using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.demo.notepad3, but I really like your suggested EasyWriter+.

Answer (score 2):

Google's own [Google Keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep&hl=it) app could be what you're looking for. Very simple (basically just copy/paste/edit and little else) and all notes can be easily synced with your Google account.

One drawback is that it doesn't directly open/edit text files, you have to type the text yourself or paste it in a new note.

Comment: Saw "*everything you add syncs across all of your devices*", but did not see off-line mode provided. I more prefer to something that much simpler than that, no online/off-line mode, no syncing, etc. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I can confirm it works perfectly even if offline, online syncing is just an extra option.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Keep, other applications you should consider are Evernote and Microsoft's OneNote.

Both Evernote and OneNote can function in stand-alone as well as syncing across platforms. Keep's advantage is that your Google login is also your Keep login. OneNote login is persistent as it is your Outlook.com or live.com login. I have found syncing OneNote at work to be problemmatic as that installation of OneNote insists on authenticating with Active Directory (AD). I haven't spent the effort to overcome that speed bump as Keep does the same with out AD. So I use Keep for notes I need for work. However, I like to separate my personal data from my work data (a lesson that Hilary Clinton has learned the hard way). Thus the inability to synch OneNote at work is a blessing as it reduces the likelihood of spillage of personal data into my employer's systems. Evernote login was also a chronic speed bump making synchronizing was a hassle.

Comment: Thanks. I'd call Evernote to be the full-featured one and Microsoft's OneNote to be the heavy duty one. They both sit on the opposite side of Android Notepad App scale than what I was looking for -- one that has the simplest features. Anyway, thanks for the input!  Up-voting -- just in case it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

## [JotterPad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotterpad.x&hl=en)

It's a beautiful text editor that saves to plain `txt` files.

> JotterPad — Writer is the next-generation plain text editor engineered for Creative writing. It is perfect for writing novel, lyrics, poems, essay, draft and screenplay. The clean typing interface allows you to focus on writing, shaping your thoughts into text. Go about your creative writing without distractions and write to your hearts content.

[image: screenshot showing JotterPad's UI]
<sup>screenshot showing JotterPad's UI (click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: For the *simplest* one, I was settled with the following, but now found it is not ad-free, and have other issues. So thumb-down on it.

**Note Pad**
Neeraj Kumar - June 26, 2014
Productivity

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.neerajkumar.mobile.android.notepad

Description

Note Pad is a simple notepad application for Android.
It's beautiful, minimalist yet powerful notes taking app that work on all Android devices with android version 2.2+.

Features:

1. Simple minimalist design. No clutter, no distracting colors.
2. Includes all the features that a note taking app should and must have.
3. Beautiful Typography.
4. Supports Android 8+ ( Android 2.2.x and above )

Answer (score 0):

FTA, I am now settled with the following,

**Notes**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.demo.notepad3

It allows me to,

- compose to-do list notes (starting every line of a note with "#")
- compose reminder,
- organize notes with labels,
- import notes from SMS

and most importantly, I found sharing to the social media is most convenient, especially when composing long messages, when you will no longer be confined to that tiny window normal social media app provides.

**UPDATE:**

As of *September 2018*, it's now off the shelf of google play. But IMHO it is still the best (1) simple (2) ***ad-free*** Android Notepad App, and available from the internet:

https://www.google.ca/search?q=com.android.demo.notepad3

Answer (score 0):

Many of the editors suggested here are either not compatible or contain ads. I found that the app Editor available on f-droid is ad-free, intuitive, and widely compatible.

Comment: You should make a declaration whether its your software or not.